# How to select author/creator field of CRM-Core Contact and Activity in views?

Tags: views

I'm building a view for [CRM-Core](https://drupal.org/project/crm_core) Contact, but I can't find the author/creator field from the Add Fields list.

I have checked the database table, there IS a column `uid`:

> The users.uid that owns this contact; initially, this is the user that created it.

Any idea about this?

And there are no permissions like `Edit own Contacts`, only permissions like `Edit any Contact`. Is it designed on purpose?

Comment: Is CRM-core your Drupal implementation or some module?

Comment: a module, see the link that I added in the post

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the permissions 'edit any contact' is designed on purpose...module maintaiers claim this allows for custom permissions to be set per your requirement.

As for author / creator field, you have to add a relationship first to your view 
Try these -

1. CRM Core Activity: Author
2. Entity Reference: Participants

That should probably expose the field you are looking for.